# select(), posix message queue and multithreading in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading

I am facing a problem about the message queue:

- I have used mq_timedreceive() to get message queue in abs_timeout time.
  But this function is affected by system time (CLOCK_REALTIME). I mean that when system time change, the abs_timeout (absolute time) is not right any more.

To fix this problem, I realize that it should change to CLOCK_MONOTOIC clock.
But in linux, there is no way (I seached and found QNX support this mechanism).

Finally, I combine select() and mq_timereceive with NO_WAIT.
+ select(): using relative time so it's not affected by system time changing.
After timeout, I will get message queue with mq_timereceive(), of course absolute time = 0;

But my problem is:
If system have many thread that are waiting the same message queue (by using select()),

- If a message is sent to message queue, all waiting thread are woken up and running. So it's wrong.
- Maybe a thread (not first waiting thread) wake up first and get this message.
- My expected is only first waiting thread should woken up and it will get message, and others still block.
  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have several questions in one:

1. Waiting on a message queue with a timeout that is not affected by clock adjustments. In Linux the following APIs support clock (`CLOCK_REALTIME`, `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, etc.) selection: `timerfd_create` and `timer_create`. One way to integrate these with `mq_timedreceive` is to let `timer_create` fire a signal that interrupts `mq_timedreceive`.
2. Integrating waiting on a POSIX message queue with `select`. The most straight-forward way would be to use [`mq_notify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_notify.3.html) to make it deliver a signal when a new message is available, thus making `select` call return `-1` and `errno` set to `EINTR`.
3. Fair queuing, so that the first waiter gets the next message. With POSIX message queues it may be possible if the waiting threads are blocked in `mq_receive`. Otherwise the next available message is delivered to a thread that calls `mq_receive` first.

For message passing between threads of the same process another approach can be to have a pipe act as a queue of message pointers. That is, a producer thread creates a message and writes a pointer to it into the pipe (i.e. no need to serialize the entire message because the message recipient is in the same process and has access to the process address space). Any consumer thread can wait on the pipe using `select` and then read the pointers to messages. However, if multiple threads are waiting on the same pipe, they all get woken up but only one of the threads will read the message pointer off the pipe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it seem that you have mis-understand my question.
My problem are: mq_timedreceive() with abs_time (>0)is affected by system time changing. so it work wrong when system time changing.
I fix this issue by combining select() timeout and mq_timedreceive() with abs_time = 0.
But when I fix the issue. I have faced 3 new issue (described in the end of the question)